# Typescript generic type inference from default value

Tags: typescript

Consider the following function.

```
public static convert<T, U>(t: T, conversion: ((toutput: T) => U) = ((t) => t)) { 
    return conversion(t);
}
```

Typescript currently complains about the toutput parameter return from the conversion function, which is the defaulted parameter:

> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'U'.
> 'U' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T'.

I'm attempting to get the IDE to recognize that, given the default parameter, T is the same as U.

My use cases are the following:

```
convert(1) // returns 1
convert(1, x => ({x})) // returns an object with { x : 1 }
```

Is there any way that anybody knows of to silence the compiler and be able to create this function above properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could accomplish this with overloads:

```
public static function convert<T>(t: T): T;
public static function convert<T, U>(t: T, conversion: (t: T) => U): U;
public static function convert<T, U>(t: T, conversion?: (t: T) => U) {
    return conversion ? conversion(t) : t;
}

..

const foo = convert(1)             // inferred type 1
const bar = convert(1, x => ({x})) // inferred type { x : number }
```

The `1` gets widened to `number` because implicit literal types are widened in the context of return values (e.g. `x => ({x})`), which in turn causes the `T` to inferred as `number`. You can avoid this by explicitly typing the first parameter:

```
const bar = convert(1 as 1, x => ({x})) // inferred type { x: 1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
static convert<T, U = T>(t: T, conversion: ((toutput: T) => U) = t => t as T & U) {
  return conversion(t);
}

const x = convert(1);
const y = convert(1, x => ({x}));
```

Use `T` as default value for `U`, and cast the return type of default value of `conversion` function as `T & U`.